# How to compare two tables using a like match based on multiple columns in SQL Server or R

Tags: sql, sql-server, matching, string-matching

I have been trying to look for a solution to this for days now. I have two tables with the following fields

- *Table 1* - `OEM_NAME, OEM_MODEL, SUPPLIER - contains 413000 records`
- *Table 2* - `OEM_Name, Model, Supplier_Name, SUPPLIER_MODEL - contains 208000 records`

The problem is that the field values do not match exactly and I am trying to implement a like comparison between the two tables that use multiple fields in the join condition. However, this query is taking forever to execute. Is there a better way of implementing a like comparison between two tables with multiple fields. I am familiar with SQL Server and R so I would really appreciate any solution/guidance that would work in one of these platforms.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM Catalog_Table as CAT
  INNER JOIN POPULATION_TABLE AS POP
  ON POP.OEM_NAME LIKE CONCAT(CAT.OEM_NAME,'%') 
   AND POP.OEM_MODEL LIKE CONCAT(CAT.MODEL,'%') 
   AND POP.SUPPLIER LIKE CONCAT(CAT.SUPPLIER_NAME,'%')
```

Update:

Sample Data:

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMnqc.png)

I also tried another approach to solve this problem. I concatenated the input fields in both the tables to form a key and tried to use this single concatenated field to perform a match - both exact and Levenshtein distance (fuzzy match)

Desired Result:

The objective here is to perform a like match and then manually scan the matched records to see if the match makes sense.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the sample data. The objective here is to use this query to perform a like match and then scan the matched records manually and determine if the match makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this out::

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Catalog_Table as CAT
INNER JOIN POPULATION_TABLE AS POP
ON POP.OEM_NAME LIKE CONCAT(CAT.OEM_NAME,'%') 
AND LEFT(POP.OEM_MODEL, LEN(POP.OEM_MODEL)-3) LIKE CONCAT(LEFT(CAT.MODEL,LEN(CAT.MODEL)-3), '%')
AND LEFT(POP.SUPPLIER, LEN(POP.SUPPLIER)-3) LIKE CONCAT(LEFT(CAT.SUPPLIER_NAME, LEN(CAT.SUPPLIER_NAME)-3), '%')
AND LEFT(POP.CATALOG_MODEL, LEN(POP.CATALOG_MODEL)-3) LIKE CONCAT(LEFT(CAT.SUPPLIER_MODEL,LEN(CAT.SUPPLIER_MODEL)), '%')
```

If you catch my drift hehehe

Comment: Hi Alfredo,

Thanks for that.. this seems to be an interesting way of performing a like match. I'll try this and will let you know how it performs.

I was able to resolve my performance issue by changing the last like match to an exact match using = symbol and that helped a lot in terms of performance of the query. However, I believe your solution would give me a lot more matches and hopefully it'll have better performance.